# Should I use grid or flexbox when I can reach same effect using older method?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I'm trying to create a gallery.How I want it to look: one image that takes 100% site width, then two 40% and 60%, again 100% e.t.c
I think grid is actually a overkill, don't know if that effect is possible using flexbox. Should I just go for old and good float:lef; ?

Comment: grid would be the choice for that case. Grid has a huge advantage: you can add as many content as you want and they will auto align into the grid. You dont have to hardcode it in HTML. It also is the betetr use for full repsonsivness on mobile devices as you can change the design more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve this with just `flex: 1` or any other number, [see the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).
Even if you can do it with good old float it's preferable to make it using flexbox because it's more performant.
Please see [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow) for in-depth details about flex performance.

Answer (score 0):

here is a flex and float example you can play with :

*Note: image do have the correct ratio to match side by side.*

**If** that does not answer your question, it should help you to clarify your question and share the code you have demonstrating your issue.

Examples below

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 0
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

div:nth-child(3n) {
  flex-grow: 6;
  max-width:62.5%;/* remove this if you want to stack on small screen */
}

div:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  flex-grow: 3.6;
  max-width:37.5%;/* remove this if you want to stack on small screen */
}

div:nth-child(3n - 2) {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/800/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1010/300/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/500/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/800/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/500/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/500/200">
</div>
```

grid example:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 3.345fr;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  grid-column: span 2
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1010/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/500/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/500/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/500/200">
```

or an old way with float :

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

img:nth-child(3n - 1) {
  width: 37.5%;
}

img:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1010/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1020/500/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1005/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/500/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1012/800/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/300/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/500/200">
```